# Appropriate way to store data

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I should to store a lot of different data and history of measurements in some storage (data from MS Kinect, ultrasonic sensor, odometry and, for example, data from infrared sensor. Sensors may be used in very different ways, not only for navigation).
I wonder, is there some convenient and native way to do this in ROS? May be somebody can share commentaries about http://wiki.ros.org/mongodb ? Or I should to use common DB like MariaDB?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80041/appropriate-way-to-store-data/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2013-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-16**:
What kind of measurement history do you want to keep? Doesn't `rosbag` suit your needs?

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2013-09-16**:
For example, we have some kind of a surveillance system. Several cameras that see a same scene from different points of view. By the end of a day, I would like to receive specific data from all sensors in such distributed system. I can use a timestamp as a key to filter data (in general, I may use as key anything, like "give me all objects with color = {}" ). I'm not sure that rosbag is appropriate way to organize this workflow. Or is it good way to store such data? May be I can write simple wrapper over rosbag that gives me DB-like interface?

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2013-09-17**:
Thank you for interesting and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something like this is possible with rosbag API in Python/C++. However rosbag is designed to store and retrieve data sequentially, thus you will have to iterate over the whole bunch of messages to find appropriate ones. So of it is not an everyday task, then rosbag should be sufficient. Otherwise it may be better to use a 'proper' DB indeed.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2